# error: expected ':' before 'BagInterface' & In Member function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

**Background**

I am new to C++ and I am working to create an object in c++ where the object can be both an array or pointer. I need to create a UNION method that can combines two BagInterface objects. I am having trouble correcting my code so that it can compile using pointers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Compile Error:**

```
 In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
 BagInterface.h:64:9: error: expected ':' before 'BagInterface'
 In file included from LinkedBag.h:43:0,
             from main.cpp:5:
 LinkedBag.cpp: In member function 'BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::Union(BagInterface<ItemType>*)':
 LinkedBag.cpp:116:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
 LinkedBag.cpp:123:3: error: 'tBagPtr' was not declared in this scope
 LinkedBag.cpp:133:3: error: 'tBagPtr' was not declared in this scope
 LinkedBag.cpp:136:9: error: 'tBagPtr' was not declared in this scope
```

**main.pp File (method):**

```
void bagTesterHW(BagInterface<string>* bagPtr)
{
//Clear Bag To Set Up Test Cases
bagPtr->clear();

//Test Clear
//displayBag(bagPtr); 

//Second Array Bag
BagInterface<string>* bagPtr2 = new LinkedBag<string>();
BagInterface<string>* bagPtr3 = new LinkedBag<string>();

//LinkedBag<string> bagPtr2; 
//LinkedBag<string> bagPtr3; 

//Test Case Strings
string items1[] = { "two", "two", "three", "four" };
string items2[] = { "two", "four" };

//Filling Linked List
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    bagPtr->add(items1[i]);
} // end for 

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    //bagPtr2.add(items2[i]); //LinkedBag
    bagPtr2->add(items2[i]);
} // end for

displayBag(bagPtr); 
displayBag(bagPtr2);

/*Problem Code
Union function not defined in Parent Object*/
bagPtr3 = bagPtr->Union(bagPtr2); 

displayBag(bagPtr3); 

/*Release Memory*/
bagPtr2 = nullptr; 
bagPtr3 = nullptr;

/*Delete Pointers*/
delete bagPtr2; 
delete bagPtr3; 

cout << "--------end bagTesterHW---------" << endl;}
```

**LinkedBag.cpp (method)**

```
template<class ItemType>
BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::Union(BagInterface<ItemType>* bagPtr)
{
BagInterface<ItemType>* = new LinkedBag<ItemType> tBagPtr;

vector<ItemType> bagItems;
bagItems = toVector();

for (int i = 0; i < bagItems.size(); i++)
{
    tBagPtr->add(bagItems[i]);
} // end for 

//Clear Items
bagItems.clear();
bagItems = bagPtr->toVector();


for (int i = 0; i < bagItems.size(); i++)
{
    tBagPtr->add(bagItems[i]);
} // end for

return tBagPtr;
}
```

**LinkedBag.h**

```
#ifndef _LINKED_BAG
#define _LINKED_BAG

#include "BagInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

template<class ItemType>
class LinkedBag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
Node<ItemType>* headPtr; // Pointer to first node
int itemCount;           // Current count of bag items

Node<ItemType>* getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const;

public:
LinkedBag();
LinkedBag(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& aBag); // Copy constructor
virtual ~LinkedBag();                       // Destructor should be virtual
int getCurrentSize() const;
bool isEmpty() const;
bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
void clear();
bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
BagInterface<ItemType>* Union(BagInterface<ItemType>* bagPtr); 

}; // end LinkedBag

#include "LinkedBag.cpp"
#endif
```

**BagInterface.h (abstract) snippit**

```
#ifndef _BAG_INTERFACE
#define _BAG_INTERFACE
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
 public:
/** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
@return The integer number of entries currently in the bag. */
virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;
. . .
/** Empties and then f ills a given vector with all entries that are in this bag.
 @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
  virtual vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;
 /** Creates a new bag that combines the contents of this bag and a
 second given bag without affecting the original two bags.
 @param anotherBag The given bag.
 @return A bag that is the union of the two bags. */ 
 //public BagInterface<ItemType> union(BagInterface<ItemType> anotherBag);
 public BagInterface<ItemType>* Union(BagInterface<ItemType>* bagPtr);
 .  .   .
 };
 #endif
```

Comment: You've posted much more code than is necessary. You need to identify and post a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

#### The First Problem

> <sup>**Compiler Error**</sup>
>
> ```
>  BagInterface.h:64:9: error: expected ':' before 'BagInterface'
> ```

```
public BagInterface<ItemType>* Union(BagInterface<ItemType>* bagPtr);
```

C++ is not java, you are missing a colon after `public`.

---

#### The Second Problem

> <sup>**Compiler Error**</sup>
>
> ```
> LinkedBag.cpp:116:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
> ```

```
BagInterface<ItemType>* = new LinkedBag<ItemType> tBagPtr;
```

The above looks very weird, both to humans, and to the compiler. What you are trying to do is initializing a `LinkedBag<ItemType>` using `tBagPtr` — as such you will need to use either parenthesis or curly brackets.

You will also need to provide a name for the object you are trying to declare.

---

#### Proposed Fixes

```
 public:
     BagInterface<ItemType>* Union(BagInterface<ItemType>* bagPtr);
```

```
BagInterface * some_name = new LinkedBag (tBagPtr);
```

Comment: BagInterface * some_name = new LinkedBag (tBagPtr); ... is this suppose to be in the Union method?

Comment: @AgustinPreciado if you want to use a `new LinkedBag` in there, surely.

Comment: ** Compiler Error ** :   `LinkedBag.cpp: In member function 'BagInterface<ItemType>* LinkedBag<ItemType>::Union(BagInterface<ItemType>*)':
LinkedBag.cpp:117:16: error: missing template arguments before '*' token
LinkedBag.cpp:117:18: error: 't' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: `BagInterface<ItemType>* tBagPtr = new LinkedBag<ItemType>;
 BagInterface  * t = new LinkedBag(tBagPtr);` This is code change.. I added the new line. Any Suggestions? I appreciate your help Filip. I again apologize for my lack of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support `public` in individual declarations. Instead you use it to mark whole sections of a class:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        void foo();
        void bar();
    private:
        int baz();
};
```

That's why the compiler is saying it's expecting a `:` after `public`.

---

The other error refers to this line:

```
BagInterface<ItemType>* = new LinkedBag<ItemType> tBagPtr;
```

It's saying it's expecting a variable name before `=`. You probably meant to write:

```
BagInterface<ItemType>* tBagPtr = new LinkedBag<ItemType>;
```

Comment: I have updated the code and the compiler is complaining on the following line:

Comment: '/tmp/ccfkQMc9.o: In function     `bagTesterHW(BagInterface<std::string>*)':main.cpp:(.text+0x7d6):     undefined reference to     bagInterface<std::string>::Union(BagInterface<std::string>*) collect2:     error: ld returned 1 exit status'

Comment: Sorry .. I am struggling with the edits on this post

Comment: `/*Problem Code
    Union function not defined in Parent Object*/
    bagPtr3 = bagPtr->Union(bagPtr2);`

Comment: **Compiler Error** `/tmp/ccW0BytG.o: In function bagTesterHW(BagInterface<std::string>*):
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d6): undefined reference to BagInterface<std::string>::Union(BagInterface<std::string>*)'`

Comment: @AgustinPreciado You can't put class/function templates in separate .cpp files. They have to be in .h files because their source has to be visible in every file that uses them.